# How to clean without dependencies in xcode4

Tags: iphone, xcode, build, xcode4, xcode3to4

Each time I need to perform a clean build for my app it takes now about 20 minutes longer than in xcode3 simply because I can't find a way to perform clean without destroying dependent static libraries. Even 'touch' function seems to be gone in xcode4. Does anybody have a solution?

UPDATE:

OK - this is how you do it.  Go to *Manage schemas* -> Click *Edit* button for your active schema -> Select *Build* target -> **Uncheck the "Find Implicit dependencies"
 checkbox** . And you will be happy with your builds again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hold down the alt key......**

as you click "Product" menu.

You will get "Clean Build Folder".

(If you forget the darn key, just type "Clean" in to the search field under "Help" menu.)  Is that what you need?  Hope it helps...

It seems strange it is taking 20 minutes, that does not seem normal. Are you in to "Workspaces" on X4 ?  (Perhaps it is relevant - I don't know.)

Comment: +1 for very usefull tip, but it deletes all the dependencies just like before.

Comment: I have old communication layer library (~400 C++ classes) that I build into a static library. If multiplied on 2 architectures (arm6/7) that adds up to 800 classes to compile. For my old mac-mini it's a fairly difficult task. Xcode3 had a nifty checkbox "Clean dependencies". If unchecked, it worked just perfect for me.

Comment: Thanks for the info. However the idea of xcode bug reporting is good option, lately I experienced so many that it's a bit discouraging. I could do it full-time.

Comment: two things about xcode4 that drives me insane. Why debugger output screen does not scroll with the output until you manually scroll all the way down. 2) They have huge problems indexing symbols in the project. Sibling resolution is utterly horrible but not as horrible as subclasses. Even if it accidentally resolves a proper simbol it will redirect you to a header file.  I like and even prefer xcode4 to 3, but they made this transition really emotional for me.